# Could not find 'ffi' (>= 1.3.0) among 85 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError) React native IOS on pod install

Tags: react-native, rubygems, react-native-ios, gemspecs

Hi I'm trying to run my react native app on mac mini. I can run another app also this app to but when i write `pod install` in terminal it gives this error.

```
1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1449:in `block in activate_dependencies'

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'ffi' (>= 1.3.0) among 85 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
    Checked in 

'GEM_PATH=/Users/xx/.gem/ruby/2.6.0:/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0', execute `gem env` for more information
```

I tryed a lot like this code

```
sudo gem pristine --all,  gem pristine --all

sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.8.4

delete and ini pod init/ which gave error
brew reinstall cocoapods
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can try this command

```sh
sudo gem uninstall -aIx
rm -rf ~/.gem
sudo gem install cocoapods

sudo chown -R $USER ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
```

Comment: Well thank you very much. It took a time to done this codes for macmini. Now it works.

Comment: Those commands not work for me. But reinstall ruby works for this issue

Comment: @Stoull can you help in installing Ruby in macOS 12 (intel)

Comment: Tried 3-4 solutions, only this one works!

Comment: Although chown command failed for me, solved the issue

Answer (score 16):

For me, install a new version of ruby resolved this issue.

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm list known
rvm install 2.7.2
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: This one worked for me. Thank you.
I had to add:
brew install --build-from-source python@3.10
xcode-select --install

Answer (score 6):

Same issue. Just updating gem package manager is works for me

`gem update`

Terminal will display installing 'ffi'

```
Successfully installed ffi-1.15.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Gem didn't work for me, run below cmd and now pod install should work like a charm

```
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved the issue by installing the command line tool for XCode.

Just download the specific CLT from apple website

Answer (score 0):

I just did a

```
bundle install
```

and that allowed me to do a pod install after upgrading (without asking me to Xcode 14).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo gem update
```

This is only soltion

Answer (score 0):

curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm list known
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin/:$PATH
rvm install 2.7.2
sudo gem install cocoapods

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).